# SQL: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm trying to write a function that joins two tables, and returns certain rows that obey a condition.

```
CREATE FUNCTION enrollment_no  (@enrollments INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(   
    SELECT *
    FROM
    dbo.Users
    INNER JOIN
    dbo.Orders
    ON
    Users.Email = Orders.Email
    WHERE
    Enrollments = @enrollments
);

SELECT *
FROM enrollment_no(4);
```

The resulting table should contain the records of users that are enrolled in 4 courses, based on the combination of the users and orders table.
When I simple run the join code, it works fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM
dbo.Users
INNER JOIN
dbo.Orders
ON
Users.Email = Orders.Email
```

But running the function instead, gives me this error.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure enrollment_no, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create function needs to be in a separate batch. Just add a **GO**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION enrollment_no  (@enrollments INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(   
 SELECT *
 FROM
 dbo.Users
 INNER JOIN
 dbo.Orders
 ON
 Users.Email = Orders.Email
 WHERE
 Enrollments = @enrollments
);

GO

SELECT *
FROM enrollment_no(4);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, an got a different error now. | 

Msg 4506, Level 16, State 1, Procedure enrollment_no, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 0]
Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'Email' in view or function 'enrollment_no' is specified more than once.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Invalid object name 'enrollment_no'.

Comment: @Fauzaan That's a different error, caused by a different issue, which is a different question. This addresses the syntax error you asked about.

Comment: @Fauzaan - the second error message seems self explanatory enough. You just need to read it.

Comment: I understand the error message, I'm confused as to why it only appears in the function, and not if I pluck it out and run it normally.

Comment: @Fauzaan because SSMS can handle displaying columns with duplicate names because thats all its doing with them, displaying them. Whereas a function needs to return a unique name per column (as the error says) because its returning a resultset that will be consumed by something which needs to be able to identify the columns.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue, fortunately: In the function, instead of `SELECT*`, I used `SELECT users.*`  - I also called the tables using an alias (so `dbo.Users as users` and `dbo.Orders as orders`). I'm quite new and not sure how it helped, but am trying to figure it out :)

Comment: @Fauzaan you shouldn't be using `SELECT *` (or `SELECT {Table Name/Alias}.*`) in production code or object definitions *at all*. **Define** the columns you want specifically: `SELECT U.UserID, U.SomeOtherColumn, O.OrderID, O.AnotherColumn, ... FROM dbo.Users U ...` (Note I use aliases for qualifying the columns too; you should really be alaising your objects to make the code more succinct).